# Metric spaces are completely normal

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(X, k)$ with $Y, Z\subset X$ and $\operatorname{cl}(Y)\cap Z  = \emptyset$, $\operatorname{cl}(Z)\cap Y = \emptyset$, prove that there are open sets $M, N$ such that $Y\subset  M$, $Z\subset N$ and $M\cap N=\emptyset$.

**My Attempt:** Since $\operatorname{cl}(Y)=Y\cup Y'$ and $\operatorname{cl}(Y)\cap Z = \emptyset$, we get: $(Y\cup Y')\cap Z = \emptyset$. Thus, $(Y\cap Z)\cup (Y'\cap Z) = \emptyset$, which means $Y\cap Z=\emptyset$ and $Y'\cap Z = \emptyset$. Similarly, $Z'\cap Y=\emptyset$. But I couldn't see how to choose $M$ and $N$ to be open sets. Can anyone please help me proceed on the remaining parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all $y \in Y$ there exist $\delta_y$ such that 
$$
B(y,\delta_y) \cap Z =\emptyset,
$$
since $y$ is not in the closure of $Z.$

Take $M=\cup B(y,\delta_y/2)$. Define $N$ analogously.

If $p \in M \cap N,$ then we have $y \in Y,z \in Z$ such that 
$$
p \in B(y,\delta_y/2) \cap B(z,\delta_z/2).
$$
If $\delta_y \leq \delta_z$ then $y \in B(z,\delta_z)$ which is not allowed. 
Similarly $\delta_z \leq \delta_y.$

Answer (score 4):

Since you call the metric space $(X,k)$, I guess $k$ is the distance function? All right, then define
$$M=\{x\in X:k(x,Y)\lt k(x,Z)\},$$
$$N=\{x\in X:k(x,Z)\lt k(x,Y)\}.$$

Comment: I just notice that your construction fails for $X=R$, $Y=(-1,0)$, $Z=(0,1)$. Clearly the conditions of the question are fulfilled, and $M=X, N=Y$ is an example of such sets whose existence is to be proven. However your construction gives $M=(-\infty,1)$ and $N=(1,\infty)$, which maximally fails the conditions that $X\subset M$ and $Y\subset N$.

Comment: @celtschk If $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual metric $k(x,y)=|x-y|,$ and if $Y=(-1,0),\ Z=(0,1),$ my construction gives $M=(-\infty,0)$ and $N=(0,\infty)$ and everything is fine.

Comment: @bot: Of course I meant $M=Y, N=Z$. However I indeed genuinely went wrong in constructing your $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 4):

i. A space $X$ is completely normal if every subspace of $X$ is normal.

ii.All metric spaces are normal.

Since subspace of every metric space is a metric space, Every subspace is normal. Thus, Metric spaces are completely normal.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X,d)$ be your metric space suppose $E,F\subset X$ are closed and disjoint. Then for each $x,y \in E,F$, there exists $\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y>$ respectively such that

$$B_{\epsilon_x}(x) \cap F = \emptyset = B_{\epsilon_y}(y) \cap E.$$

Then I claim the disjoint open sets containing $E,F$ to be

$$U=\bigcup_{x \in E}B_{\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}}(x), V=\bigcup_{y \in F}B_{\frac{\epsilon_y}{2}}(y).$$

To show theyre disjoint assume toward a contradiction and use triangle inequality.